# Comparing two arrays using sections?

Tags: java, arrays, integer, compare

Given two arrays `P` of length `k` and `R` of length `s>k`.

```
P = {p1,p2,p3 ... pk}
R = {r1,r2,r3,r4 .. rs}
```

for example;

```
int [] P = {2,1,4,5};
int [] R = {2,3,4,1,2,6,7};
```

How would I go about comparing sub sections of array `R` with `P` of length `k`? i.e. `R[1..k]`, `R[2..k+1]` etc.

Will be comparing to find out the closest match of P in R

Comment: Looks similar to the [`diff` algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility#Algorithm) to me.

Comment: Show us the code you have tried and tell us what the result should be for your example.

Answer (score 0):

Loop from `i=0; i <= R.length - P.length`

Use [Arrays.copyOfRange](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(T[],%20int,%20int)) to make a copy of `R` from `i` to `i+P.length`. Then use [Arrays.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(short[],%20short[])) to compare `P` and the copy of `R`.

This is memory intensive but easy to follow.